# DrRacket: function call: expected function, given: (list ...)

Tags: list, scheme, racket

This is a Code, which 'removes' duplicates:

```
(define (positions list)
   (sort (foldl (lambda (x y) (if (not (member? x y)) (append (list x) y) y)) empty list) <))
```

When I tested this:

```
(positions (list 3 4 4 5 8 9 4 1 2 9))
```

I get an error `function call: expected function, given: (list 3 4 4 5 8 9 4 1 2 9)`

But when I replace `(list x)` with `(cons x '())` it works. Why? Aren't both the same?

Comment: I believe that `list` is a built-in function supplied by scheme. It looks like you are shadowing that with your own parameter `list` in your function. Try renaming that to `l` or something else.

Comment: It worked. Thank you.

Comment: Look at the part "shadowing procedures"